# iOS6 autorotation. TabBar->Navigation->Modal

Tags: iphone, rotation, ios6

I've read almost every answer about the new iOS6 autorotation stuff but I still can't manage to do what I want.

I have a tabBar. One of the tabs is a NavigationView. When you turn the iPhone to landscape, a modalViewController is loaded.

Everything works ok on iOS5 but I can't get the modal view to rotate on iOS6. I've tried subclassing the navigation controller, subclassing the tabbar controller and both!. No way.

I'm now very confused. Which one is the responsible of rotating the modalview?. The tabbarController?, the navigationViewController?, the viewController who presented it?.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: [self presentModalViewController:newController animated:YES]; is deprecated in iOS6 , try [self presentViewController:newController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: I look forward to see this answered. I'm having the same problem too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS6 you have to change the rotation of the application.
application.statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;

Comment: It works!. I know it's just a workaround but it saves my day. Thank You. :D

Answer (score 0):

***Autorotation is changing in iOS 6.*** 
In iOS 6, the [*shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation*:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a) method of [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIViewController) is deprecated. In its place, you should use the [supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow%3a) and [shouldAutorotate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotate) methods.

More responsibility is moving to the app and the app delegate. Now, iOS containers (such as [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UINavigationController)) do not consult their children to determine whether they should autorotate. By default, an app and a view controller’s supported interface orientations are set to [UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll) for the iPad idiom and [UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown) for the iPhone idiom.

A view controller’s supported interface orientations can change over time—even an app’s supported interface orientations can change over time. The system asks the top-most full-screen view controller (typically the root view controller) for its supported interface orientations whenever the device rotates or whenever a view controller is presented with the full-screen modal presentation style. Moreover, the supported orientations are retrieved only if this view controller returns `YES` from its [shouldAutorotate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotate)  method. The system intersects the view controller’s supported orientations with the app’s supported orientations (as determined by the `Info.plist` file or the app delegate’s [application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3asupportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow%3a) method) to determine whether to rotate.

The system determines whether an orientation is supported by intersecting the value returned by the app’s [supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow%3a) method with the value returned by the [supportedInterfaceOrientations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations) method of the top-most full-screen controller.

The [setStatusBarOrientation:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarOrientation%3aanimated%3a) method is not deprecated outright. It now works only if the [supportedInterfaceOrientations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations) method of the top-most full-screen view controller returns `0`. This makes the caller responsible for ensuring that the status bar orientation is consistent.

For compatibility, view controllers that still implement the [shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a) method do not get the new autorotation behaviors. (In other words, they do not fall back to using the app, app delegate, or `Info.plist` file to determine the supported orientations.) Instead, the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method is used to synthesize the information that would be returned by the [supportedInterfaceOrientations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations) method.

The [willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willRotateToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a), [willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a), and [didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation%3a) methods are no longer called on any view controller that makes a full-screen presentation over itself—for example, [presentViewController:animated:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a).

You should make sure that your apps are not using these methods to manage the layout of any subviews. Instead, they should use the view controller’s [viewWillLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews) method and adjust the layout using the view’s bounds rectangle.

Reference - [iOS 6.0 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html)

Hope this may help you

Comment: Sorry, I should have wrote that I already knew that. I have all orientations supported in target's summary. I have subclassed the navigationController AND the tabBarController allowing the orientations and setting shouldAutorotate to YES. The same in the view that presents the modal and the view presented itself. Still, no rotation. What am I missing?

Comment: kindly see the 5th paragraph my answer

Comment: You're right, Bala. Sorry, I missed that. Kudos for your help.