# UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown showing error while making a build

Tags: iphone, ios6, autorotate

I am making an app having deployment target 4.3, but my base SDK is 6.0.

Now when I make build then the compiler is showing error about usage of `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown`.

Comment: If you aren't getting warning in your project, I would suggest doing a search in your project for `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13431733/1059705 Take a look at it.. that might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

that symbol isnt defined in 4.3 and so it doesnt work :)
ios6 changed how VCs tell it about supported rotations

implement the old way using shouldAutorotate: